# ASPM: Could not configure common clock

Tags: linux, power-management

It is not the first time that I see this message in a Linux system, on boot:

```
ASPM: Could not configure common clock
```

I figured out that it has to do with [Active State Power Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_State_Power_Management).

I've found the [source code in the Linux kernel that prints this message](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e53f9a28bee35932a0ae4d2ec2784f55491ec6d3/drivers/pci/pcie/aspm.c#L242) and [the commit that introduced it](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2a42d9dba7842422ffb2c02e75288a8bc2fd5065). But I feel that reading that source code would send me on a long learning journey.

So, what does this mean? Should I strive to correct it? Is it a hardware error? Driver error? Perhaps I could configure something in the BIOS?

Comment: What hardware, kernel, distro, setup are you running? Guess: Lenovo laptop, discreet graphics using nVidia?

Comment: I hope [this](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7144614.html?sid=03e4ed3b450b5f4457538d8b327ef5d6#7144614) might help

Comment: I'm not trying to solve any specific issue, other than whatever that message means. Other than seeing this message, I don't see anything wrong with the system. I'm assuming that power management may be not optimal.

Comment: I have the same message here on a Thinkpad T60 with ATI graphics card.  Doesn't seem to cause any real problem, but I'm also curious what it means.

Comment: Weird that no solution for this case exists. I had the same problem and i just changed my pci gpu with another that needs less power to be able to proceed with Ubuntu installation.